# How can one access a base class method using base class object once it has been overwritten?

Tags: oop, system-verilog

This question might be applicable to all/most Object-oriented programming languages but I am only concerned about the SystemVerilog side.
Polymorphism, I thought I understood, until I was talking to a colleague the other day and this came and I realised that I don't know how this can be done.
Following are the two classes to consider for the purpose of this discussion -

```
class four_wheeler;

    virtual function void vehicle_type();
        $display("Four-wheeler");
    endfunction:vehicle_type

    virtual task colour();
        $display("Many colours");
    endtask:colour
endclass:four_wheeler

class jaguar extends four_wheeler;

    function void vehicle_type();
        $display("Jaguar");
    endfunction:vehicle_type

    task colour();
        $display("Black");
    endtask:colour
endclass:jaguar

program sv_prog;

  initial begin
    four_wheeler four_wheeler_h;
    jaguar  jaguar_h;

    four_wheeler_h = new();
    jaguar_h = new();

    four_wheeler_h = jaguar_h;
    four_wheeler_h.vehicle_type();

  end

endprogram: sv_prog
```

I want to access the `vehicle_type()` function in the base class four_wheeler using its own object. I can do this by `four_wheeler_h.vehicle_type()` before the `four_wheeler_h = jaguar_h` copy. Regular OOP working! But can I do it after the copy of the handle? 
I can use the `super` keyword in jaguar class `vehicle_type()` method:

```
function void vehicle_type();
    super.vehicle_type();
    $display("Jaguar");
endfunction:vehicle_type
```

and get the output:

```
Four-wheeler
Jaguar
```

But I am more interested in doing this from the program block itself without having to modify the function in the jaguar class. Is there any way I can achieve that? Maybe a use of `super` from the program block itself.

Comment: I think you need to describe a real use case for what you are trying to achieve. For your example, why bother making vehicle_type a virtual method?

Comment: It actually is a hypethetical question to understand the abilities/limitations of the language.

Comment: There could be a use case where I want to access the base class method and derived class method - both, using only the base class object, in that case I need to make the base class method virtual, but then I lose access to that method if I have to, at some point later, access it. So my question to you too, can I somehow, 'un'pass the derived class handle to base class variable and be able to access the base class method after having accessed the derived class method first (for which I had passed the derived class handle to the base class variable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I afraid that unlike in c++, you are very limited in the ways of doing it (like in java). So, all languages are different.

Similarly to java, SystemVerilog provides you with the keyword 'super' which you can use in class members. You will have to create a specific class member function for access its base(super)-class members in the non-class scope:

```
class jaguar extends four_wheeler;
   ...

   function super_vehicle_type();
     super.vehicle_type();
  endfunction

endclass:jaguar
```

now you can use

```
jaguar_h.super_vehicle_type();
```

you can also use class scope identifier in the function to access any of the base classes.

```
   function super_vehicle_type();
     four_wheeler::vehicle_type();
  endfunction
```

In the above case you can use any of the base classes (instead of the four_wheeler) as a class scope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From this, I understand that it cannot be done in SystemVerilog, directly from the program block, without having to modify the derived class. 
So that should also mean that there is no way to 'un'pass the derived class handle to base class variable, because if we could do that, we could achieve what we are trying for here.(?)

Comment: No, there is no such way. All variables pointing to class objects in SV are references (same as in java). A references always reference objects created by the `new` operator. So, even if you assign a reference of derived class to a reference of a base class, it still will point to the derived class. The only way around it is to construct another object of the base class and copy  base values from the derived one. something like `four_wheeler fw_h = new(jaguar)`. But you need to provide a corresponding constructor to the `four_wheeler`.

Comment: Thank you, Serge. I'll experiment with the workaround in some time.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is a **no**, that's not how virtual methods work. Polymorphism defines it in such away that you are not supposed to be aware that you are dealing with an overridden class object. It's like asking if you've declared a member as `local` or `protected`, is there any way to access that member from outside the class. The answer to that is **no** as well. *But*... there are ways that you can control access to those member variables and methods if you provide additional accessor methods in the base class.

```
class base;
  local int base_variable;
  virtual function void do_this;
  endfunction
  function int get_base_variable;
     return base_variable;
  endfunction
  function void base_to_this;
     base::do_this();
  endfunction
endless
```

Comment: Thank you, dave_59. And that encapsulation analogy is a good way to explain the real reason why polymorphism exists.